# Install components before custom actions

Tags: custom-action, wix3.7

My setup app should create user in sql server and restore a database. I do it as two separate projects;one to copy the database backup file to the machine, and the other one to do the actions. I'm planning to make it a single project.

```
  <Fragment>  
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">      
       <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder" Name="Program Files"  >
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="My Produact name" >
            <Directory Id="DBDIR" Name="DB PreReq"  ></Directory>
          </Directory>
       </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <UI Id="DbConfigSetupUI"  >      
      <TextStyle Id="DlgFont8" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" ></TextStyle>
      <TextStyle Id="DlgTitleFont" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" Bold="yes" ></TextStyle>
      <UIRef Id="Custom_WixUI_Mondo" />      
      <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
      <InstallUISequence >               
          <Custom Action="CreateUserWithSa"  Before="FileCost"  >NOT Installed</Custom>          
          <Custom Action="CreateUserWithWindows" After="CreateUserWithSa"  >(SARETURN="fail") AND NOT Installed</Custom>
          <Show   Dialog="ConnectionStringDialog" After="CreateUserWithWindows"   >(WINDOWSRETURN="fail") AND NOT Installed</Show>
          <Custom Action="CreateUserWithPrompt"  After="ConnectionStringDialog" >(DBLOGIN AND PASSWORD) AND NOT Installed</Custom>        
          <Custom Action="CreateDB"  After="CreateUserWithPrompt" >(SARETURN="pass" OR WINDOWSRETURN="pass" OR PROMPTRETURN="pass") AND NOT Installed</Custom>        
      </InstallUISequence>      
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
```

Here the files are not being copied(components are placed in a separate file), but the custom actions are being done. Since the backup file is necessary to restore. I need that to happen first. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schedule your custom action to run after InstallFinalize in the InstallExecuteSequence. You are guaranteed that your files will be installed by that point. Be warned you will need to store your property/data values if your action needs to access them.

Comment: Moved the custom action 'CreateDB' to install execute sequence with after InstallFinalize and it worked

Comment: Stein Asmul has a response somewhere here in StackExchange that describes the actions between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize very well. Windows installer will queue the actions between those two and scheduling custom actions within them is something you really should understand before you do it. I've always been safe and not scheduled custom action between those 2 if I can avoid it.

Thanks for the +1